# how to stream web URL as video on YouTube android programmatically with youtube apis

Tags: android, youtube, web, video-streaming

how can i stream web url on YouTube using with youtube apis in my android app. just like check this video...

//video is not live at the moment, just stored as normal video..it is just for reference, this shows how an URL showing in video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRrQYTMXW7U

the original web URL is here: 
http://nextcricket.com/live-score-board/Kalai-brothers-vs-11-spratan-75885942026

how can i do with Server URL (YouTube)  and Stream name/key (YouTube) .. Anyone with this key can live stream on my YouTube channel. i.e I want to use my channels  Server URL and Stream name/key to post videos on my channel